# How to match two different image which has lots of repetitive feature?

Tags: image-processing, template-matching, feature-descriptor

Suppose we have two image. One of them is a template image, the other is a source image acquired from camera.
As the usual template match algorithm, a regoin in the source image is highly similar to the template image. However, there are some slight differences between them so that traditional template match algorithm fails.
One more important detail in the images is that there are lots of repetitive feature in the image. I tried some feature match algorithm, they all failed in this situation.

[A PCB image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnMfk.png)

[SIFT: good case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpQ6X.png)

[SIFT: bad case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDgC.png)

Is there any solution or suggestion about this?
Some traditional algorithm  will be better!

Comment: Could you please post a few sample images showing typical cases ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, I uploaded  a PCB image as a typical case.

Comment: I don't see significant differences between template and images, and I can't imagine why traditional template matching would fail, on the opposite. Also note that there is only translation (and 180° rotation), making the task especially easy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust haha, at first, i also vote for template matching. However there is significant different in color. Besides, the images i uploaded were low resolution. Something different will be found if we look at the high resolution image.

I am wondering is there any techniques can ignore the effect of the color and focus on the content like edge and corner? I've also tried to begin with edge detection like canny. Sometimes it fails.

Comment: The effect of color is cancelled by using normalized correlation, which is what I call traditional template matching. By the way, there is no need to use a color image, grayscale is good enough. Local differences will have no significant impact, NGC is quite robust.